# Create multiple Java Threads at once

Tags: java

Is there any possibility to create the threads as follows,

```
Thread odjhygThread= new Thread(objJob1, objJob2);
```

I think we couldn't, if we want to create what needs to be done?
anyone knows the answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain.

Comment: I want to run 2 Jobs.
I have initialized thread counts in property file.
No_HygThreads=6
Hyg_jobs=bns and cns jobs
 But in this i want to run 2 jobs.

what i want to do is,

I hav to run 6 Threads in parallel,These 6 threads for two JObs.
My code should work for following scenarios:
1) To run 4 bns jobs, and 2 cns jobs in parallel
2) To run 2 bns jobs, and 4 cns jobs in parallel
3) To run 3 bns jobs, and 3 cns jobs in parallel
4) To run 6 bns jobs, and Zero cns jobs in parallel, and so on.
We want to run bns and cns in parallel,we can trigger 6 jobs in parallel

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944291/threads-in-java by the same author.

Answer (score 4):

A Thread runs one job. That's the way they are designed.

If you are trying to run two jobs, use two Threads.

If you want to hand over two jobs to be run in the background, read the JavaDocs for the [Executors](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class, and the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) class. It will take you a while to get your head around them, but unfortunately that's the nature of multi-threading in Java. Complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is what you're aiming for but.. Create a class that extends Thread, and give it a c'tor that takes 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (unless I am missing something here)

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private final Object object1;
    private final Object object2;

    public MyThread(Object o1, Object o2) {
        //implicate call to super()
        object1 = o1;
        object2 = o2;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //ha ha
        //he he
        //ho ho
        //off to work we go
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're already aware of the Thread constructor that takes a Runnable as an argument.  Are you trying to create a thread that calls run() on two different Runnable objects?  This doesn't exist, but it would be easy to write:

```
public class RunTwoThings implements Runnable {

  private Runnalbe thing1;
  private Runnable thing2;

  public RunTwoThings(Runnable thing2, Runnable thing2) {
    this.thing1 = thing1;
    this.thing2 = thing2;
  }

  public void run() {
    thing1.run();
    thing2.run();
  }

}
```

You'd might want to do some exception handling to prevent problems in thing1 from preventing the execution of thing2.  Then, just create a new thread like so:

```
Thread odjhygThread= new Thread(new RunTwoThings(objJob1, objJob2));
```

If that's not what you're trying to do (e.g. if you want them both to run simultaneously in their own threads), you probably want Steve M.'s answer above.